# Why is startActivityForResult not showing up in recycler view adapter?

Tags: java, android-activity, android-recyclerview, startactivityforresult

I am new to android programming. I am unable to find startActivityForResult(intent) within onBindViewHolder in the recycler adapter.
I have a recycler view adapter containing some items for MainActivity(1). This Activity 1 contains some elements which are hidden. If the user clicks on any item, he/she is taken to a new activity(2). Activity2 contains a button, which when clicked, changes the items in Activity 1 to be visible.

On doing some research, I found that I need to use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity if I am expecting results back from Activity2. But I am unable to find startActivityForResult(intent) within onBindViewHolder in the recycler adapter for Activity1.

Am I doing something wrong? Below is the recycler view code

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.txtItem.setText(items.get(position).getItemName());
    holder.txtShortDesc.setText(items.get(position).getItemShortDesc());

    holder.txtShortDesc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LongDesc.class);
            intent.putExtra(ITEM_ID_KEY, items.get(position).getId());
            startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Comment: You need to call startActivityForResult with your activity1 instance, something like activity1 startActivityForResult. You may need to pass a reference of your activity to the adapter.

Comment: pass the context to the adapter and then type `context.startActivityForResult()`

you already did that, use` mContext.startActivityForResult`

Also remember that when you finish of the activity Set the result to OK and then finish it

Comment: how do I pass mainActivity context to the recyclerview Adapter? Below is the code within the MainAcitivity:itemRecViewAdapter adapter = new itemRecViewAdapter(this);
        itemRecView.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: I have used ((MainActivity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,999); to pass the context for MainActivity into the recycler view adapter. Thank you for the help @pablobu and Basil Battikhi. But I am unable to continue with the next step, which is adding onActivityResult method. Even after using the activity 1 context, I am unable to find the mind the method. Can you help me understand where and how can I add this method to continue with getting results from Activity 2?